# Any existing implementations of Dictionary that are garbage free?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-4.0

We have an enormous program that is generating too much garbage. This is hurting performance, generating thousands of soft page faults every second, reducing latency, hurting throughput, etc.

One of the prime culprits is `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`, so we would like to replace it with a version that allows us to pre-allocate say 10,000 entries, then reuse these entries on the fly.

Are there any existing implemenations of `Dictionary` that allow pre-allocation of entries, and do not generate garbage at runtime?

Comment: Have you tried using the `Dictionary` constructor with 10,000 as its capacity? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk84bxf4.aspx

Comment: What are your TKey and TValue, and are you using the generic or non-generic API to access it?

Comment: A dictionary grows at an O(log N) rate. Its not nessesarily certain that predefining the amount of elements will help you with garbage collection problems. When encountering these problems, it would be wise to relook your strategy. Is it really nessesary to allocate so many dictionary instances?

Comment: What is the garbage you refer to?

Comment: 10.000 Key,Value pairs can hardly be the problem.

Comment: Look deeper. Hash is Int32. Dictionary is built for a lot more than 10,000. I use Dictionary int, int with up to 1 million often with no problems.  Are you putting some large objects in dictionary?

Comment: @Marc Gravell. We are using a generic API to access it. TKey is an int, TValue is a class.

Comment: @jeffamaphone The normal garbage that is generated by the .NET runtime. Google "C# garbage collection".

Comment: @Blam The question was never about the range of keys you can put into a dictionary. The question was about an implementation of dictionary that does not generate garbage, at runtime, behind the scenes.

Comment: OK and I did not vote down you question.  I had a GC problem reusing a Dictionary.  Newing is not GC friendly but .Clear() is GC friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We decided not to use the garbage free dictionary in the end, as it didn't impact overall GC that much.

For the record, here is an implementation of a garbage free dictionary. Its memory hungry, but it works well.

To use, instantiate a new dictionary, with enough slots for the potential integer keys. For example, if the primary integer key could range between 0 and 50,000, then you will need to pass 50,000 in when you instantiate it:

```
MyIntegerKeyDictionary = new MyIntegerKeyDictionary<int, MyClass>(50000);
```

If the key could range from 200,000 to 250,000, instantiate it with 50,000 potential keys, and it will automatically "rebase" the key (based on the first key it sees) so it can range from 200,000 to 250,000.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using MyLogType;

namespace MyHelper
{
/// <summary>
/// NOTE: Non thread safe, only run this individually.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of item we are adding to the dictionary.</typeparam>
public class MyIntegerKeyDictionary<T> where T : class
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Array in which we store the entries.
    /// </summary>
    volatile private T[] ArrayToUse;

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows us to check the maximum size, just in case.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly int SizeInternal;

    /// <summary>
    /// Keeps track of the current number of items in the dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    public int Count = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Base number. For numbers that start with a huge base, this allows the index to work without allocating megabytes of memory.
    /// </summary>
    private int BaseNumberToAdd { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Size">Size of the dictionary.</param>
    public MyIntegerKeyDictionary(int Size)
    {
        // Create the array to hold n number of items.
        ArrayToUse = new T[Size];

        // We must touch all of these entries, to force page faults now (rather than later).
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayToUse.Length; i++)
        {
            ArrayToUse[i] = null;
        }
        BaseNumberToAdd = int.MinValue;

        this.SizeInternal = Size;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add an item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Key">Key.</param>
    /// <param name="Value">Value.</param>
    /// <returns>True if the item was added, false if not.</returns>
    public bool TryAdd(int Key, T Value)
    {
        if (BaseNumberToAdd == int.MinValue)
        {
            BaseNumberToAdd = Key;
            //Console.Write(string.Format("{0}Message W20120907-3751. TryAdd. Adding first item {1}.\n",
            //MyLog.NPrefix(), Key));
        }
        Key = Key - BaseNumberToAdd;

        if (Key < 0)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0}Warning W20120907-3750. TryAdd. Attempted to add a key with index {1} which is < 0.\n",
                MyLog.NPrefix(), Key));
            return false;
        }

        if (Key >= this.SizeInternal)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0}Warning W20120907-3756. TryAdd. Attempted to add a key with index {1} which is > max {2}\n",
                MyLog.NPrefix(), Key, this.SizeInternal));
            return false;
        }

        if (ArrayToUse[Key] == null)
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref Count);
        }

        ArrayToUse[Key] = Value;
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove an item from the dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Key">Key that we want to remove.</param>
    /// <returns>True if the item could be removed, false if not.</returns>
    public bool TryRemove(int Key)
    {
        if (BaseNumberToAdd == int.MinValue)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0}Warning W20120907-8756. TryRemove. Attempted to remove an item without any items in the dictionary yet {1}.\n",
                MyLog.NPrefix(), Key));
            return false;
        }
        Key = Key - BaseNumberToAdd;


        if (Key < 0)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0}Warning W20120907-9756. TryRemove. Attempted to remove a key with index {1} which is < 0.\n",
                MyLog.NPrefix(), Key));
            return false;
        }

        if (Key >= this.SizeInternal)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0}Warning W20120907-6756. TryRemove. Attempted to remove a key with index {1} which is > max {2}\n",
                MyLog.NPrefix(), Key, this.SizeInternal));
            return false;
        }

        if (ArrayToUse[Key] != null)
        {
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref Count);
        }

        ArrayToUse[Key] = null;

        return true;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Indexer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">Key.</param>
    /// <returns>Value.</returns>
    public T this[int key]
    {
        get
        {
            T valueToReturn;
            TryGetValue(key, out valueToReturn);
            return valueToReturn;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempt to get the value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Key">Key.</param>
    /// <param name="Value">Value.</param>
    /// <returns>True if the value exists, false if not.</returns>
    public bool TryGetValue(int Key, out T Value)
    {
        Value = null;
        if (BaseNumberToAdd == int.MinValue)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0}Warning W20120907-8756. TryGetValue. Attempted to retrieve an item without any items in the dictionary yet {1}.\n",
                MyLog.NPrefix(), Key));
            return false;
        }
        Key = Key - BaseNumberToAdd;
        if (ArrayToUse[Key] == null)
        {

            return false;
        }

        Value = ArrayToUse[Key];
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks to see if the key exists.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Key">Key index.</param>
    /// <returns>True if the item exists, false if not.</returns>
    public bool ContainsKey(int Key)
    {
        if (Key == 0)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0}Warning W20120907-1914. ContainsKey. Have not rebased yet. Ignoring query for ContainsKey(0).\n",
                MyLog.NPrefix()));
            return false;
        }

        if (BaseNumberToAdd == int.MinValue)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0}Warning W20120907-8756. ContainsKey. Attempted to check if Key {1} exists, however BaseNumber is not set yet.\n",
                "", Key));
            return false;
        }
        Key = Key - BaseNumberToAdd;

        if (Key < 0)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0}Warning W20120907-8756. ContainsKey. Key = {1} which is < 0.\n",
                "", Key));
            return false;
        }

        if (Key >= this.SizeInternal)
        {
            MyLogAsync.LogWarning(string.Format("{0}Warning W20120907-5756. ContainsKey. Key({1}) >= this.SizeInternal ({2}).\n",
                MyLog.NPrefix(), Key, this.SizeInternal));
            return false;
        }

        if (ArrayToUse[Key] == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    /*
    private bool CheckKeyBounds(int Key, string description)
    {
        if (Key < 0)
        {
            MyLogAsync.LogWarning(string.Format("{0}Warning W20120907-8756. {1}. Attempted to add a key with index {2} which is < 0.\n",
                MyLog.NPrefix(), description, Key));
        }

        if (Key >= this.SizeInternal)
        {
            MyLogAsync.LogWarning(string.Format("{0}Warning W20120907-5756. {1}. Attempted to add a key with index {2} which is > max {3}\n",
                MyLog.NPrefix(), description, Key, this.SizeInternal));
            return false;
        }
    }
    */
}
}
```